# Using Typescript decorators with Parse SDK JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, parse-platform, parse-server, typescript-decorator

I'm using Parse SDK JS in my Typescript project and I created a model class `Person`, extending `Parse.Object`, that will be used to same data on the server:

```js
import * as Parse from 'parse/node'

class Person extends Parse.Object
{
    @ParseField
    name: string

    @ParseField
    age: number

    constructor() {
        super('Person')
    }
}
```

And I also created a **property decorator** called `@ParseField` that will inject a getter and setter on each field with the code to properly assign and retrieves the values from a `Parse.Object`.

The `@ParseField` decorator looks like this:

```js
import * as Parse from 'parse/node'

function ParseField<T extends Parse.Object>(target: T, key: string): void
{
    const getter = () => {
        return target.get(key)
    }

    const setter = (value: unknown) => {
        target.set(key, value)
    }

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    })
}
```

And finally, I try to save the `Person` class in the Parse Server:

```js
const p = Person()
p.name = 'John'
p.age = 30
p.save().then(obj => console.log(obj))
```

But when the `Parse.Object` is saved on the server the fields `name` and `age` are undefined. I put some breakpoints in the setter of `@ParseField` and I can see that it's called when I assign some value, like `p.name = 'John'` or `p.age = 30`.

Does anybody know what's wrong in my implementation?

Comment: It it's using `JSON.stringify` to serialize the object, prototype members will be ignored, only own, enumerable properties are considered. Unfortunately, we can't place the property directly on the instance because the decorator runs on the class `prototype`, that's what `target` actually is. You could do something like check for an own property whenever the get or set runs and redefine them on the instance if they don't exist.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Do you have an example of how that could be done?

Comment: I can try to write one up but it is a confusing hack, will likely break in the future, and is hard to maintain

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution on how to get this to work?  Looking for something similar to help introduce better type safety into our code base

Comment: @TWilly No, I didn't. Actually I gave up on using Parse. I posted the same question in their official forums and a moderator removed it because he found my original question here in Stackoverflow and he claimed that "I shouldn't post the same question in two places..." - Well, he didn't realize that I posted there simply because I couldn't find an answer here. Anyway, they were less than helpful so I'm using something else now.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to hit this when looking for the answer. Challenge with the decorator above is that `target` is the object prototype and not the instance, so you're calling set/get on the wrong object.

This decorator works for me:

```
export function ParseField<T>(target: Parse.Object, key: string): void
{
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: function () {
            return this.get(key)
        },
        set: function (value: T) {
            this.set(key, value)
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```